# mysql5.6 installer keeps installing to wrong folder

Tags: windows-7, installation, mysql

I'm trying to install mysql 5.6 with the installer. However for some reason it starts the install in the correct folder but then continues the install into this folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Canon\Easy-WebPrint EX\ directory.
```

I've uninstalled a couple of times but still wants to install here. I've specified another folder in the custom set up option but still goes wrong

I've found a number of threads across the net and on the mysql forums with this issue but I can t seem to find a work around.

How can I completely unintsall and remove all references to the mysql install and canon folder

How can I check the install configuration to ensure it goes to the right location?

Any ideas?

My OS is win 7 64bit

Comment: ta.speat: I agree that MySQL is not a knight in shining armour, but this is not helping the OP.  @Ray: what happens of you uninstall mySQL, reboot, run a registry cleaner and then reinstall, or if you temporarily rename the canon folder?

Comment: Hi. I've uninstalled and clean the registry, and completely remove the canon folder but it still want to install there. It seems the installers config files want it to go there. I've uninstalled any canon product as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing [MySQL manually](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-installer-msi-quiet.html):

Open a cmd prompt and type the following->

> msiexec /i "mysql-5.x.x.msi" /quiet INSTALLDIR="C:\Program
>   Files(X86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.x"

Please adjust "mysql-5.x.x.msi" path/filename, and the folder you want to install MySQL into...

Comment: Thanks - finally managed to get it to install correctly. I also removed any entry in the registry for canon easy web print. once installed I was then able to install the latest updated as well which went straight to the correct folder. I have another question now which i'll start in a new thread - thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason is a registry setting which should not be there:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

directly (and NOT in a subkey, as it should be) contains the entries InstallLocation, UninstallString and a few more that relate to the Canon software.

Just delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\InstallLocation and MySQL Server installs into the "correct" location.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68227